# Unable to run connect-distributed.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs

I get the below error when I am executing the command.. My kafka messages are not flowing down into hdfs

/bin/connect-distributed.sh /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties /kafka-connect/quickstart-hdfs.properties

```
 ERROR Failed to start task local-file-source-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:456)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy for configuration key.subject.name.strategy: Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:718)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1063)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:168)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:207)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:369)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:382)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.baseConfigDef(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.java:153)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverterConfig.<init>(AvroConverterConfig.java:27)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:63)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:434)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:865)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1600(DistributedHerder.java:110)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:880)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:876)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

`connect-distributed`only takes one property file, not two. The quickstart files are meant to be used with connect-standalone

The actual error you're getting about the topic name strategy is likely an issue/bug with the version of the Avro serializers you're using

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the information.. I continue to get the error even after running with only one file..

Comment: Like I said, it could be an issue with the Avro serializers you're using. You should try reporting here if you have a brand new installation / are using latest versions https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues